# scp-ing while ssh'd into remote machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

#### My desire:

`ssh` into a remote machine, take a peak around, and then copy a file from from that remote machine into my local machine using a Linux command.

#### My frustration:

From what I've seen in the documentation, I can't be `ssh`'d while using the `scp` command. I must simply be a user on my local machine and specify the the connection info and the file location (ie. `scp user@remotehost:copyFrom.txt /myDir/copyHere.txt`).

I could alternatively use SFTP:

```
$ SFTP user@remotehost
$ $ get remoteFile.txt /myLocalDir/localFile.txt
```

but [SFTP isn't quite as fast as SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/134901/whats-the-difference-between-scp-and-sftp).

*Is it possible to use `scp` while already `ssh`d into the remote machine?*

Comment: Would like to know why this question is marked as off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, if you don't have public IP and `sshd` server running on your workstation (if you have, there is nothing easier than to run `scp file localmachine:` from remote session).

The speed is not significant. It can be one or two percent on large files, but using `sftp`, you will gain much more, because you do not have to initiate `ssh` the connection for each `scp` command, but only once and every `get` command is "cheaper". For normal files over normal network you will not notice difference.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on condition: "if you don't have public and sshd server..." If I have these, can I run that command and accomplish my goal? (`scp fileName localmachine:`)

Comment: sorry, there was missing "IP". If you have, you can use `scp` from that remote session to your local workstation just as you do other way.